# Finding a matrix representation of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

> **Exercise:**
>
> Consider the vector space of $R^{2×2}$ and the linear operator $L_{A,B} : R^{2×2} → R^{2×2}$ given by
>
> $$L_{A,B}(X) = AX + XB$$
>
> where
>   $A=$ 
>   \begin{bmatrix}
> 3 & 4 \\\
> 1 & 2\end{bmatrix}
>
> and $B=$
>   \begin{bmatrix}
> 5 & 6 \\\
> 7 & 8
> \end{bmatrix}
>
> Find the matrix representation of $L_{A,B}$ with respect to the basis
>   $$\left( \begin{bmatrix}
> 1 & 0\\ 
> 0 & 0
> \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
> 0 & 1\\ 
> 0 & 0
> \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
> 0 & 0\\ 
> 1 & 0
> \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
> 0 & 0\\ 
> 0 & 1
> \end{bmatrix} \right)$$

What I did was calculating the matrix after the linear transformation. But I think that is not what I should do. Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: The coordinates of the image of the basis elements are the columns of the matrix representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since

- $L\left(\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]\right)=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}8&6\\1&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$;
- $L\left(\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]\right)=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}7&11\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$;
- $L\left(\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]\right)=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}4&0\\7&6\end{smallmatrix}\right]$;
- $L\left(\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]\right)=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&4\\7&10\end{smallmatrix}\right]$

the matrix that you are after is$$\begin{bmatrix}8&7&4&0\\6&11&0&4\\1&0&7&7\\0&1&6&10\end{bmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Just let $X=\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$ and explicitly compute $AX+XB$. Then the linear operator sends the column vector $(a,b,c,d)^T$ to another column vector whose entries correspond to the coefficients in entries of $AX+XB$:
$$L_{A,B}=\begin{bmatrix}
8&7&4&0\\
6&11&0&4\\
1&0&7&7\\
0&3&6&10\end{bmatrix}$$